# TreeMap using Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, treemap

JAVA:

I want to create a TreeMap using a Binary Search Tree using Entry, however my class BST:

`public class BST<V> implements Iterable<V>{}`

doesn't like if in my TreeMap class:

`public class TreeMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {`

I decide to implement a new instance of that class of the type Entry as follows:

`private BST<Entry<K,V>> theMap;`

I know it works for ArrayLists, so it must be something with my BST class, but for the love of me I can't figure out what it is.